# Content of Xamarin Fragments in ListView diappearing when scrolling

Tags: listview, android-fragments, xamarin, mvvmcross, android-7.0-nougat

We have an android app built with Xamarin and mvvmCross. We have an activity with an mvxListView and dynamically add a good amount (~between 10 and 80) of fragments to it. The fragments only have one visible label and click behavior.

When the app is run on a device with Android 7(Nougat) some fragments do not have content, the label and the click behavior is missing. It's not always the same fragment and when the list is scrolled - some fragments leave the viewport while others enter - some fragments regain content and others lose it. Only a few of the fragments are lacking content, most on the screen are working normally.

This behavior does not occur on older versions of android, tested on various  devices with version 4-6. Behavior occured on all devices with Andoid 7.

Does anyone have an idea what could cause this? Did memory managment for lists change in nougat?